# Developing Win CE app on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-mobile, windows-ce

Is it possbile develop an application for Windows CE 5 on Visual Studio 2010 ?

I've tried to install the WinCE 5 SDK bundled with my device but when i try to install give me an error "Destination platform unsupported", seems that the package require Windows XP and Visual Studio 2005 ...

I'm on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Device development (except Windows Phone) must be done in Studio 2008 (or Studio 2005).

Comment: At least Visual Studio Professional 2008 or 2005,the express version won't allow for device development

Comment: 2005 can be Standard edition (it was Pro in '03, then back to Pro in '08).  Correct, no Express SKU can be used.